# How to Translate SQL statement to Linq

Tags: linq-to-sql

I don't know how to translate Sql statement with join and  subquery  to linq..Following is sql statement which i trying to translate ..Please help

```
Select product.Name from product where Product.Id in( select ProductId from 
SaleDetail s join Sale s1 on s.SaleId=s1.Id where s.SaleId in(select Id from Sale  where sale.CustomerId=17264))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this (where db is the linq data context):

```
var result= (
        from p in db.Product
        where
            (
                from s in db.SaleDetail
                join se in db.Sale
                    on s.SaleId equals se.Id
                where
                    (
                        from s2 in db.Sale
                        where s2.CustomerId==17264
                        select s2.Id
                    ).Contains(s.SaleId)
                select s.ProductId
            ).Contains(p.Id)
        select new
        {
            p.Name
        }
    );
```